# Uniform closure of polynomials

Tags: terminology, operator-theory, spectral-theory, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

What is the meaning of "uniform closure of polynomials"? 
I have seen it in Conway's *Functional Analysis* book VII § 5.

Comment: Maybe it's the set of uniform limits of polynomials?

Comment: As a concrete example. take the polynomials  $\mathbb P=\left \{ {p:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R} \right \}$ and give $\mathbb P$ the uniform topology. Then the closure of this set is $\mathbb C([0,1])$.

Answer (score 1):

The full quote is:

> If $\partial\mathbb{D}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$, let $B=$ the uniform closure of the polynomials in $C(\partial\mathbb{D})$.

This means: consider the set of all continuous functions on $\partial\mathbb{D}$, equipped with the uniform norm $\|f\|=\sup_{\partial \mathbb{D}}|f|$. This space is denoted by $C(\partial\mathbb{D})$. Polynomials form a subset of this space. The closure of this subspace is the set of all limits of uniformly convergent sequences of polynomials.

For example, the function $z\mapsto \exp(z)$ belongs to this closure, because the sequence of partial sums of the exponential function converges uniformly on the unit circle. On the other hand,  the conjugation $z\mapsto \bar z$ does not belong to the closure, which can be proved with the argument principle (its values move the  wrong way around $0$ as we trace the circle).

Comment: An alternative to the argument principle is using that the family $(z^n)_{n \in \Bbb{Z}}$ is orthogonal in $L^2 (\partial \Bbb{D})$.

Comment: So if B is the uniform closure of the polynomials in C(rond D)